# Lightning strike pressure on object

Tags: electromagnetism, pressure, charge, lightning

I am doing research on the behavior of lightning strikes and how they affect objects they hit. I have found this article that gives some information about lightning, like speed, length, temperature, and width of lightning:
https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/weather/learn-about/weather/types-of-weather/thunder-and-lightning/facts-about-lightning

Also, I have found that the electrical charge of lightning is between 14 C and 18 C. What I need is to find the pressure that average lightning exerts on the lightning rod. I am interested in ways to measure the pressure and mechanical stress that a lightning strike can cause in a lightning rod and if that can cause the rod to oscillate vertically or horizontally so that pressure sensor tapes can be used to measure the change in rod tangential and radial pressure after a lightning strike.

I need to know what is the average pressure expected from lightning and how to calculate it.

Comment: I've closed this question because it goes against our policy on "check my work" questions. But I like the question and I think it can be made on-topic. Your next [edit] will put the question in front of community members who review candidate questions for reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pressure from a lightening strike is not due to a lot of electrons hitting the target (some strikes are opposite polarity), but because of the explosive heating of the air in the discharge.

One way of estimating the pressure is the ideal gas law: $PV=nRT$. In lightening $T$ increases from ca 300 K to about 25,000 K, a factor of about 83. Meanwhile the volume $V$ and number of particles $n$ are initially the same, so the pressure $P$ has to increase by the same amount to balance the equation. That gives me 83 atmospheres, or $8.41\cdot 10^6$ Pa.

This is not too far from the original estimate (likely more by luck), and [a bit lower than estimates in the literature of about 100 atm overpressure](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.23907/2016.008). 25,000 K may be on the low end for lightening temperature. Also, when it hits an object there will be a pressure-shockwave-object interaction that may boost pressure ([ch 3 p. 13](https://skybrary.aero/sites/default/files/bookshelf/3352.pdf)).